# Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?

Tags: c#, compilation, dynamic-compilation

I was wondering if it is possible to save C# code fragments to a text file (or any input stream), and then execute those dynamically? Assuming what is provided to me would compile fine within any Main() block, is it possible to compile and/or execute this code? I would prefer to compile it for performance reasons.

At the very least, I could define an interface that they would be required to implement, then they would provide a code 'section' that implemented that interface.

Comment: I know this post is a few years old, but I thought it worth mentioning with the the introduction of [Project Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), the ability to compile raw C# on the fly and run it within a .NET program is just a little bit easier.

Comment: Yes, plz see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74984054/3057246 for example

Comment: @VinodSrivastav thanks I will absolutely go check out a question that was asked 3 years after I posted mine and a comment that was posted 14 years after my original question. Thanks very much for your feedback

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The best solution in C#/all static .NET languages is to use the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) for such things. (As a note, its other main purpose is for dynamically constructing bits of code, or even whole classes.)

Here's a nice short example take from [LukeH's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx), which uses some LINQ too just for fun.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"using System.Linq;
            class Program {
              public static void Main(string[] args) {
                var q = from i in Enumerable.Range(1,100)
                          where i % 2 == 0
                          select i;
              }
            }");
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
}
```

The class of primary importance here is the `CSharpCodeProvider` which utilises the compiler to compile code on the fly. If you want to then run the code, you just need to use a bit of reflection to dynamically load the assembly and execute it.

[Here](https://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/) is another example in C# that (although slightly less concise) additionally shows you precisely how to run the runtime-compiled code using the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Comment: Although I doubt your using Mono, I thought it might be worthwhile pointing out that there exists a Mono.CSharp namespace (http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) which actually contains a compiler as a service so that you can dynamically run basic code/evaluate expressions inline, with minimal hassle.

Comment: what would be a real world need for doing this. I'm pretty green at programing in general and i think this is cool but i can't think of a reason why you would want / this would be useful. Thanks if you can explain.

Comment: @Crash893: A scripting system for pretty much any sort of designer application could make good use of this. Of course, there are alternatives such as IronPython LUA, but this is certainly one. Note that a plugin system would be better developed by exposing interfaces and loading compiled DLLs that contain implementations of them, rather than loading code directly.

Comment: I always thought of "CodeDom" as the thing which let me create a code file using a DOM - a document object model.  In System.CodeDom, there are objects to represent all the artifacts that code includes - an object for a class, for an interface, for a constructor, a statement, a property, a field, and so on.  I can then construct code using that object model.  What is shown here in this answer is compiling a code file, in a program. Not CodeDom, though like CodeDom, it dynamically produces an assembly. The analogy: I can create an HTML page using the DOM, or using string concats.

Comment: here's a SO article that shows CodeDom in action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865052/programatically-generating-assemblies-from-owl-files-with-rowlex

Comment: @Cheeso: CodeDom has *both* of these purposes: to compile source code into assemblies as well as to generate code dynamically.

Answer (score 91):

[You can compile a piece C# of code into memory and generate assembly bytes](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn) with Roslyn. It's already mentioned but would be worth adding some Roslyn example for this here. The following is the complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;

namespace RoslynCompileSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // define source code, then parse it (to the type used for compilation)
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
                using System;

                namespace RoslynCompileSample
                {
                    public class Writer
                    {
                        public void Write(string message)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(message);
                        }
                    }
                }");

            // define other necessary objects for compilation
            string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location)
            };

            // analyse and generate IL code from syntax tree
            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                assemblyName,
                syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
                references: references,
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // write IL code into memory
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    // handle exceptions
                    IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic => 
                        diagnostic.IsWarningAsError || 
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                    foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // load this 'virtual' DLL so that we can use
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());

                    // create instance of the desired class and call the desired function
                    Type type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Writer");
                    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    type.InvokeMember("Write",
                        BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                        null,
                        obj,
                        new object[] { "Hello World" });
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same code that C# compiler uses which is the biggest benefit. Complex is a relative term but compiling code on runtime is a complex job to do anyway. However, the above code is not complex at all.

Answer (score 42):

Others have already given good answers on how to generate code at runtime so I thought I would address your second paragraph.  I have some experience with this and just want to share a lesson I learned from that experience.

> At the very least, I could define an
>   interface that they would be required
>   to implement, then they would provide
>   a code 'section' that implemented that
>   interface.

You may have a problem if you use an `interface` as a base type. If you add a single new method to the `interface` in the future all existing client-supplied classes that implement the `interface` now become abstract, meaning you won't be able to compile or instantiate the client-supplied class at runtime.

I had this issue when it came time to add a new method after about 1 year of shipping the old interface and after distributing a large amount of "legacy" data that needed to be supported.  I ended up making a new interface that inherited from the old one but this approach made it harder to load and instantiate the client-supplied classes because I had to check which interface was available.

One solution I thought of at the time was to instead use an actual class as a base type such as the one below.  The class itself can be marked abstract but all methods should be empty virtual methods (not abstract methods).  Clients can then override the methods they want and I can add new methods to the base class without invalidating existing client-supplied code.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Foo1() { }
    public virtual bool Foo2() { return false; }
    ...
}
```

Regardless of whether this problem applies you should consider how to version the interface between your code base and the client-supplied code.

Comment: that is a valuable, helpful perspective.

Answer (score 15):

Found this useful - ensures the compiled Assembly references everything you currently have referenced, since there's a good chance you wanted the C# you're compiling to use some classes etc in the code that's emitting this:

(string `code` is the dynamic C# being compiled)

```
        var refs = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var refFiles = refs.Where(a => !a.IsDynamic).Select(a => a.Location).ToArray();
        var cSharp = (new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider()).CreateCompiler();
        var compileParams = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(refFiles);
        compileParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
        compileParams.GenerateExecutable = false;

        var compilerResult = cSharp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compileParams, code);
        var asm = compilerResult.CompiledAssembly;
```

In my case I was emitting a class, whose name was stored in a string, `className`, which had a single public static method named `Get()`, that returned with type `StoryDataIds`. Here's what calling that method looks like:

```
        var tempType = asm.GetType(className);
        var ids = (StoryDataIds)tempType.GetMethod("Get").Invoke(null, null);
```

Warning: Compilation can be surprisingly, extremely slow. A small, relatively simple 10-line chunk of code compiles at normal priority in 2-10 seconds on our relatively fast server. You should never tie calls to `CompileAssemblyFromSource()` to anything with normal performance expectations, like a web request. Instead, proactively compile code you need on a low-priority thread and have a way of dealing with code that requires that code to be ready, until it's had a chance to finish compiling. For example you could use it in a batch job process.

Comment: Your answer is unique. Others do not solve my problem.

Comment: That's a neat idea to give all the referenced assemblies in the currently running code to the assembly you are compiling. I had to give the compiled assembly even some more referenced assemblies using compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add().

Comment: I'm hoping this approach will solve a problem I have in unit tests in which the CodeDOM generated code has references to classes in identical assemblies as those currently loaded, but from a different folder, but can't find its types during execution.

Answer (score 5):

I recently needed to spawn processes for unit testing. This post was useful as I created a simple class to do that with either code as a string or code from my project. To build this class, you'll need the `ICSharpCode.Decompiler` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` NuGet packages. Here's the class:

```
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler.CSharp;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler.TypeSystem;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class CSharpRunner
{
   public static object Run(string snippet, IEnumerable<Assembly> references, string typeName, string methodName, params object[] args) =>
      Invoke(Compile(Parse(snippet), references), typeName, methodName, args);

   public static object Run(MethodInfo methodInfo, params object[] args)
   {
      var refs = methodInfo.DeclaringType.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(n => Assembly.Load(n));
      return Invoke(Compile(Decompile(methodInfo), refs), methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName, methodInfo.Name, args);
   }

   private static Assembly Compile(SyntaxTree syntaxTree, IEnumerable<Assembly> references = null)
   {
      if (references is null) references = new[] { typeof(object).Assembly, typeof(Enumerable).Assembly };
      var mrefs = references.Select(a => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(a.Location));
      var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(Path.GetRandomFileName(), new[] { syntaxTree }, mrefs, new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
         var result = compilation.Emit(ms);
         if (result.Success)
         {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
         }
         else
         {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Join("\n", result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic => diagnostic.IsWarningAsError || diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error).Select(d => $"{d.Id}: {d.GetMessage()}")));
         }
      }
   }

   private static SyntaxTree Decompile(MethodInfo methodInfo)
   {
      var decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler(methodInfo.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location, new DecompilerSettings());
      var typeInfo = decompiler.TypeSystem.MainModule.Compilation.FindType(methodInfo.DeclaringType).GetDefinition();
      return Parse(decompiler.DecompileTypeAsString(typeInfo.FullTypeName));
   }

   private static object Invoke(Assembly assembly, string typeName, string methodName, object[] args)
   {
      var type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
      var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
      return type.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, args);
   }

   private static SyntaxTree Parse(string snippet) => CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(snippet);
}
```

To use it, call the `Run` methods as below:

```
void Demo1()
{
   const string code = @"
   public class Runner
   {
      public void Run() { System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@""C:\Temp\NUnitTest.txt"", System.DateTime.Now.ToString(""o"") + ""\n""); }
   }";

   CSharpRunner.Run(code, null, "Runner", "Run");
}

void Demo2()
{
   CSharpRunner.Run(typeof(Runner).GetMethod("Run"));
}

public class Runner
{
   public void Run() { System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\NUnitTest.txt", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("o") + "\n"); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To compile you could just initiate a shell call to the csc compiler.  You may have a headache trying to keep your paths and switches straight but it certainly can be done.

[C# Corner Shell Examples](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/ShellCommandsInCS12032005042031AM/ShellCommandsInCS.aspx)

**EDIT**: Or better yet, use the CodeDOM as Noldorin suggested...

Comment: Yeah, the nice thing with CodeDOM is that it can generate the assembly for you in memory (as well as providing error messages and other info in an easily readable format).

Comment: @Noldorin, The C# CodeDOM implementation doesn't actually generate an assembly in memory. You can enable the flag for it, but it gets ignored. It uses a temporary file instead.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, good point - I forgot that fact. Nonetheless, it still greatly simplifies the process (makes it effectively *appear* as if the assembly were generated in memory), and offers a complete managed interface, which is much nicer than dealing with processes.

Comment: Also, the CodeDomProvider is just a class that calls into csc.exe anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ASL
{
    class Program
    {
        [Obsolete]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string code = @"
                using System;

             namespace First
             {
                public class Program
                {
                  public static void Main()
                    {
                        " +
                        "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");"
                        + @"
                    }
                }
             }";
            Console.WriteLine(code);
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            // Reference to System.Drawing library
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
            // True - memory generation, false - external file generation
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            // True - exe file generation, false - dll file generation
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
            }
            Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type program = assembly.GetType("First.Program");
            MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");
            main.Invoke(null, null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a class for daily use.

```cs
var code =
"""
string Execute(int[] a){
    a[0]++;
    System.Console.WriteLine("Dynamic!");
    return "done";
}
""";
var a = new[]{1,2};

var execute = DynamicCompilation.CompileFunction<int[], string>(code,typeof(Console));
var result = execute(a);
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
System.Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
Dynamic!
done
2
```

As you can see it compiled method `Execute` into delegate.

It referenced `System.Console` by passing it's type as param after code.

It modified object in my main program memory.

It returned some value to my main program thread that I can use.

It is very slow at first run (1 sec on my machine)

It is fast on secondary runs (60-100 ms on my machine)

install `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`

Copy paste class into your code and use.

See for class here
https://gist.github.com/Kemsekov/a3e1c011425fd789d12cea8764acea97

Answer (score 0):

There is also `CSharpScript` from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` nuget. Not sure if this is the most suitable/performant way but I will put it here just for sake to list all possibilities.
Example:

```
public class ScriptGlobalVariables()
{
    public string[] EnumItems;
}

    private static Script<string[]> CreateScript()
    {
        string[] imports = ["System", "System.Linq"];
        var options = ScriptOptions.Default
            .AddReferences(typeof(Func<,>).Assembly)
            .AddReferences(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly)
            .AddImports(imports);
        var code =
$$"""
    Func<string, string> transformer = x => "prefix_" + x;
    return EnumItems.Select(transformer).ToArray();
""";

        var script = CSharpScript.Create<string[]>(code, options, typeof(ScriptGlobalVariables));
        script.Compile();
        return script;
    }
```

And exection:

```
var script = CreateScript();
script.RunAsync(new ScriptGlobalVariables() { Items = items });
```