# How to create class at runtime from file

Tags: c#, parsing

Is it possible to create a class at runtime from a file without parsing it?

If not what would be the best approach to retrieve class properties, constructors and methods from a file? Taking into account that a file could have more than one class just like a typical cs file.

Comment: What does this question have to-do with regex? Also duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a class at runtime from a file.

[Dynamic Source Code Generation and Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Runtime Compiler (Reflection) in MS.NET

Take a look [here](http://www.aboutmydot.net/index.php/compile-and-execute-code-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET take a look at [BuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getcompiledassembly.aspx).

Here's an example usage:

```
Assembly a = BuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly("~/TestClass.cs");
foreach (Type t in a.GetExportedTypes()) {
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
    // Do something with obj...
}
```