# attach an integer to an exe file on user-request through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, download, exe

I have no experience on this matter, so I do not expect anyone to explain in details how this is done, just point me in the right direction, maybe tell me what the correct name for this is. I'm sure it is pretty commonly in use.

I think the best way to explain this, is through my exact need. So, I have a button on my website that should cause the user to download an exe file. The exe file pretty much gathers a few informations from the users PC, and post them to my data-base through a web-service. Now my problem is, these informations should be assigned to the user who downloaded the exe file's row in the DataBase.

All this would be solved by assigning a single Integer value(the users ID) to this exe file on the download request, and then a way for the exe file to also get this value assigned to it, but how do I do that?

My language is asp.net for my website, and the exe file is written in vb.net.

---

I know I could fake this by making the exe file show a login-form and get the user-id this way, but I really like the application run without the user noticing to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably much better solutions, but an alternative would be to [dynamically compile an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments).

I imagine that the problem with this approach is that it would take too much time and resources to do it on a server. Also, changes to the application would be difficult to apply.