# Execute .NET code at runtime

Tags: .net

Suppose i write 'piece of code' in a text file. 
Is it possible to read that file at runtime and...execute ? 
For example, suppose my software have a **method1**, **method2** and **method3** methods.
In a text file i write any simple piece of code, like:

```
dim i as integer
i = method1() + method2()
console.write(i)
```

How can execute it dinamically, at runtime ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeDOMProvider and the [System.CodeDom.Compiler Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6b99ydt.aspx) is where you will want to start. But you will have to write more extensive code than your sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider.aspx) for both VB and C#