# from string variable how to class initializaton is possible

Tags: c#, .net

is it possible to initialize a class by a string variable? my syntax is bellow:

```
string sClassContainer="
class a
{
    Property1;
    Property2;
}"
```

how do I do this in c#?

Comment: What format is the string in? You probably have no other choice but to parse it and create a class on the fly. Is the class definition  already known?

Comment: Do you mean you want to somehow instantiate the class "a", which is defined in the string "sClassContainer"? Something likethis?: `var instanceOfA = MyClassGenerator.CreateInstance(sClassContainer);` I think I understand what you're asking, but not whether it is possible.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this code? If you have some specific task to solve, maybe there is some other easier way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it would be nearly useless. Even with older .NET versions you could use [How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655/en-us)... But then? You can use it only through reflection (technically, if your "new" class implements an interface or override some virtual methods of a base class, you can then create it through reflection and use it through the interface/base class)

See here for a complete example [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

I'll add that in C# 4.0 you can use `dynamic` to create "dynamic" "classes".

```
dynamic myObj = new ExpandoObject();
myObj.Prop1 = "Hello";
myObj["Prop2"] = "World. Today is ";
string myPropName = "Prop3";
myObj[myPropName] = DateTime.Now;
```

(as noted by SaeedAmiri with `dynamic` I'm not creating a class, I'm creating a dynamic object. In this case "class" would mean [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) "classes". So if you create a dynamic object that has a field `WalkLikeADuck`, then anyone that needs `WalkLikeADuck` can use it even if the object isn't really a `Duck`)

Comment: In your example you create an specific object, not specific type.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I consider it to be Duck Typing. `When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck.` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: :))) very interesting I never heard that :))).  but I think it's not so, because type can be used too many times, if sample is what the OP wants (in fact) you are right, but otherwise it's not a duck :)