# How do I use external c# pages

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

I know that it is not the norm, but I am building something that needs to access, and then use, an external .cs file, that can be in the same namespace.

I am not looking for better c# protocol or what's normally done. In all the research that I've done prior to this question, everyone said that's not the norm. But I know that, and I'm still wondering if there is a way to do it.

thanks so much =)

Comment: By "use" do you mean dynamically compile and execute?

Comment: yes. That's exactly what I mean

Comment: See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate. I didn't know it was called "Dynamically compiling and executing" so it didn't come up in any of my searches =/

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately for you, this is already in the framework: [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)