# Need help trying to call from a .txt file after compilation

Tags: vb.net, browser

It's me Mr. Confusing again.

I am trying to add this code (call this code) from a .txt file on my computer after run time.

Before compilation I can add this code to my form and it runs great by manually placing the webbrowser.navigate & addhandlers under a button and the rest by itself, but I am wanting to add this code after my app is compiled using by clicking a button.

My thought process on this was to have the code done in a .txt like I have and then before compiliation go into the btn1 on my form and code it to say whatever .txt I open using the openfiledialog pull the code into the form and use it.

I know that manually just placing the webbrowser.navigate and the addhandlers under the button manually (and adding the hanlders and public new instance of the form) will do the trick but there has to be a better way of going about this seeing that I am going to have about 500 .txt files to draw from.

I was thinking of maybe looping through a folder and grabbing each .txt in the folder and calling them into the form by doing something??? but I'm lost at this step.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks

Here is the code from one of the .txt files.

```
'Connotea DECLARATION
Public Connotea as new captchawindow

Public Sub ConnoteaNavigate
Connotea.webbrowser1.navigate("http://www.connotea.org/register")
End Sub

Public Sub ConnoteaHandlers

AddHandler Connotea.button1.click, addressof Connoteabutton
AddHandler Connotea.webbrowser1.documentcompleted, addressof Connoteabrowsercompleted
End Sub

Public Sub Connoteabrowsercompleted

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "firstname" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.FirstName.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "lastname" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.LastName.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "username" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Username.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "password" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Password.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "passwordconfirm" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Password.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "email" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Email.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "email2" then
element.setAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Email.Text)
End If
Next

If Connotea.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
For Each Captcha As HtmlElement In Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Images
If Captcha.GetAttribute("src").Contains("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=") Then
Connotea.PictureBox1.Load(Captcha.GetAttribute("src"))
End If
Next
End If


End Sub

Public Sub Connoteabutton

Connotea.show

For Each element as HtmlElement in     Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("id") = "recaptcha_response_field" then
element.setAttribute("value", Connotea.Textbox1.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element as HtmlElement in             Connotea.WebBrowser1.Document.Getelementsbytagname("input")
If element.getattribute("value") ="register" then
 element.InvokeMember("click")
End If
Next

Connotea.dispose
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the solution you are looking for it using [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments) is in C# but should give you some pointers.

[This article on the microsoft site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304654) gives a step by step guide to achieving this in VB