# Execute code lines from a text file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, text

I have a text file looks like:

```
AssembleComponent Motor = new AssembleComponent;
AssembleComponent Shaft = new AssembleComponent;
......

Motor.cost = 100;
Motor.quantity = 100;
Shaft.cost = 10;
Shaft.quantity = 100;
......
```

I wish to execute these code lines in C#, so that I will have these Motor.cost, Motor.quantity, Shaft.cost, Shaft.quantity variables stored in the memory for later calculation.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/826398/380384

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, as the problem can be solved without executing any code lines from a file. Rather, only values are stored in the file, instead of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it as XML instead

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Components>
    <Component name="Motor" cost="100" quantity="100" />
    <Component name="Shaft" cost="10" quantity="100" />
</Components>
```

Assuming that you have this definition

```cs
public class AssembleComponent
{
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Load it like this

```cs
var components = new Dictionary<string, AssembleComponent>();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Oli\Desktop\components.xml");
foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Descendants()) {
    string name = el.Attribute("name").Value;
    decimal cost = Decimal.Parse(el.Attribute("cost").Value);
    int quantity = Int32.Parse(el.Attribute("quantity").Value);
    components.Add(name, new AssembleComponent{ 
                             Cost = cost, Quantity = quantity
                         });
}
```

---

You can then access the components like this

```
AssembleComponent motor = components["Motor"];
AssembleComponent shaft = components["Shaft"];
```

Note: Creating the variable names dynamically by calling the compiler at runtime is not very useful since you need to know them at compile-time (or design-time if you prefer) to do something useful with them. Therefore, I added the components to a dictionary. This is a good way of creating "variables" dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry for not accepting your answer in time as I wasn't aware of this function :D.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile code on-the-fly.

Specifically, take a look at [CompileAssemblyFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If it's just about data don't use a flat textfile but XML-instead.

You can deserialize the XML in to objects and perform the necessary actions on them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that I've used in the past, that does *most* of what you want though you may need to adapt it to your specific needs.  In a nutshell, it does the following:

- Create a temporary namespace and a public static method in that namespace.
- Compile the code to an in-memory assembly.
- Extract the compiled method and turn it into a delegate.
- Execute the delegate.

At that point it's like executing a normal static method, so when you say you want the results in memory for later use, you'd have to figure out how that would work.

```
public void CompileAndExecute(string CodeBody)
{
    // Create the compile unit
    CodeCompileUnit ccu = CreateCode(CodeBody);

    // Compile the code 
    CompilerParameters comp_params = new CompilerParameters();
    comp_params.GenerateExecutable = false;
    comp_params.GenerateInMemory = true;
    comp_params.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;
    comp_results = code_provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(comp_params, ccu);

    // CHECK COMPILATION RESULTS
    if (!comp_results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        Type output_class_type = comp_results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("TestNamespace.TestClass");

        if (output_class_type != null)    
        {    
            MethodInfo compiled_method = output_class_type.GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);    
            if (compiled_method != null)    
            {    
                Delgate created_delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker), compiled_method);
                if (created_delegate != null)
                {
                    // Run the code
                    created_delegate.DynamicInvoke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (CompilerError error in comp_results.Errors)
        {
            // report the error
        }
    }
}

public CodeCompileUnit CreateCode(string CodeBody)
{
    CodeNamespace code_namespace = new CodeNamespace("TestNamespace");

    // add the class to the namespace, add using statements
    CodeTypeDeclaration code_class = new CodeTypeDeclaration("TestClass");
    code_namespace.Types.Add(code_class);
    code_namespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));

    // set function details
    CodeMemberMethod method = new CodeMemberMethod();
    method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static;
    method.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(void));
    method.Name = "TestMethod";

    // add the user typed code
    method.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetExpression(CodeBody));

    // add the method to the class
    code_class.Members.Add(method);

    // create a CodeCompileUnit to pass to our compiler
    CodeCompileUnit ccu = new CodeCompileUnit();
    ccu.Namespaces.Add(code_namespace);

    return ccu;
}
```

Comment: What is `code_provider` ? it's not defined without it it's a non working code

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

1. Expand the text until it becomes valid C# code, compile it and execute it
2. Parse it and execute it yourself (i.e. interpret it).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done following these steps: **`CodeGeneration` => `InMemory Compilation to Exe` ==> `Execution`**.

You can design the construct similar to this:

```cs
public bool RunMain(string code)
{
    const string CODE_NAMESPACE = "CompileOnFly";
    const string CODE_CLASS = "Program";
    const string CODE_METHOD = "Main";

    try
    {
        var code_namespace = new CodeNamespace(CODE_NAMESPACE);

        // add the class to the namespace, add using statements
        var  code_class = new CodeTypeDeclaration(CODE_CLASS);
        code_namespace.Types.Add(code_class);
        code_namespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));

        // set function details
        var method = new CodeMemberMethod();
        method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static;
        method.ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(void));
        method.Name = CODE_METHOD;

        // add the user typed code
        method.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetExpression(code));

        // add the method to the class
        code_class.Members.Add(method);

        // create a CodeCompileUnit to pass to our compiler
        CodeCompileUnit code_compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        code_compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(code_namespace);


        var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
        compilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        compilerParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;

        var code_provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        var comp_results = code_provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, code_compileUnit);

        if (comp_results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (CompilerError error in comp_results.Errors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
            }

                   
            throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
        }

        //Get assembly, type and the Main method:
        Assembly assembly = comp_results.CompiledAssembly;
        Type program = assembly.GetType($"{CODE_NAMESPACE}.{CODE_CLASS}");
        MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod(CODE_METHOD);

        //runtit
        main.Invoke(null, null);
        return true;

    }
    catch(Exception compileException)
    {
        Console.Write(compileException.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the code above we are actually creating a simple console `Program.Main()` as

```cs
namespace CompileOnFly
{
    internal class Program
    {
       static void Main()
        {
            //<your code here>  
        }
    }
}
```

in memory then compiling it as executable in Memory and executing it. But the `Main()` body `//<your code here>` is added dynamically with the parameter `code` to the method.

So If you have a script in the text file `script.txt` as this:

```
Console.Write("Write your name: ");
var name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Happy new year 2023 " + name);
```

You can simply read all the text and send it as parameter to it:

```
 var code = File.ReadAllText(@"script.txt");
 RunMain(code);
```

To run the statements in the `script.txt` file.

---