# Create c# functions after the project has been compiled

Tags: c#, function, dynamic

I am curious as to if this is even possible. Is it possible to create a c# exe project with a rich text box that if I typed in for example

```
public void TestFunction(){
    MessageBox.Show("test");
};
```

that it would execute the code and build the function? I don't know if this makes sense. It was just one of those little questions that I had today and I don't know where to find the answer or what it is even called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments :):)

Comment: @ByteBlast Confused why you linked to exactly the same question I did, seven minutes later... O_o

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I just didn't know what to call it in order to find it. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

ofc. it possible.
See [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) namespace

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to write an interpreter and compiler.

Yeah those sort of things exist, that's how your code works.

Otherwise there are the Reflection classes built into C# which might work for some small stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible using reflection but it is a lot of hard work...