# Implementing a simple C# code parser

Tags: c#, .net

My program should find `Console.WriteLine("` in the source text box and start reading the string just after the `"` until it finds a `")`, and then store the captured string in a variable. For example, if the input is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
```

Then the variable's value should be `Hello World`.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question properly.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I got it

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Comment: `String.IndexOf` may be enough for described task... But from title you want more - you need to make clear how far you want to go with parsing and what libraries you are willing to use/are allowed by your assignment.

Comment: `string result = input.Replace("Console.WriteLine(\"", "").TrimEnd('"', ')', ';');`

Comment: With edits it's pretty clear what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

```
string yourInput = ...
var result = Regex.Match(yourInput, "Console.WriteLine[(]\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\"[)]").Groups[1].Value;
```

A little test:

```
string yourInput = "Console.WriteLine(\"\\\") Yeahhh\")"; 
yourInput += "Console.WriteLine(\"At least Regex can handle \"this\"\")";
yourInput += "Console.WriteLine(\"Although \"Regex\" is afraid of parsing \"text\" with nested elements\")";
var matches = Regex.Matches(yourInput, "Console.WriteLine[(]\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\"[)]");
foreach (Match m in matches)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Output

```
\") Yeahhh
At least Regex can handle "this"
Although "Regex" is afraid of parsing "text" with nested elements
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("\") Yeahhh")"` - regex are hard :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you mean that string is unable to be matched with `Regex`? I've tested it and \ is the result :)

Comment: But it should be `\") Yeahhh` (Sorry I typed `"` instead of last `;`: `Console.WriteLine("\") Yeahhh");`)

Comment: 100% of the strings I've tried have failed. Maybe you could add what strings you've tried and how the regular expression works.

Comment: `@"\(""(.+)""\)"` would be sufficient. Also, @user814064 Your string literals have to look like `@"Console.WriteLine(""hello World"")"` to actually be `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's right. can't match `nested element`, but for the `OP's description`, the desired string starts from `Console.WriteLine("` to the second `"`, if he means he wants to match all the string between `(...)`, that's not possible with regex.

Comment: @jdphenix Why `.+?` instead of `.+`? Also it's not a valid string (with quotes).

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I discovered my brainfart a few seconds ago, yeah back to my coffee...