# how to make dynamic identifiers to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I want to create 20 array with 4 member. It should be like

```
          a1[1]=2, a1[2]=3, a1[3]=4, a1[4]=5

          a2[1]=6, a2[2]=7, a2[3]=8, a2[4]=9

                     ......
```

we can do this with m. dimensional arrays like a[1,1]=2 ... which I cant use.

Is there anything like this

```
        for(int a=1;a<21;a++)
         {
            string al="a"+a;
            int[] al=new int[];
         }
```

so we can create dynamic identifiers?

Comment: **Why** can't you use multi dimensional arrays? That would be the way to go...

Comment: What is is that you are trying to accomplish? Using dynamic identifiers in a compiled language is rarely a good idea, as they are as both difficult to create and use.

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro I know it doesnt make sense but I attend a class this week which is more likely at beginner level for now. So you'r telling it is not possible without using m.dimensional arrays or Dictionary class?

Comment: @emmett Never said that. Multi-dimensional would be the ideal way of solving this. Now, the algorithm to locate the **worst** path between two points has infinite solutions. There are multiple ways of doing this, one worse than other.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use multi-dimensional arrays you could use a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
for(int a=1;a<21;a++)
{
   string al="a"+a;
   dict.Add(al, new int[]);
}
```

Comment: I wonder why OP can't use multi-dynamic arrays but would be able to use a Dictionary...

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro True.  It's a bit of a mystery.

Comment: +1 for the approach, but that would go along with a -1 to the "requirement".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for collections with a dynamic size would probably be to use a

List < List < int > >

For a fixed size I think you can just use new int [20, 4]

Unfortunately can't seem to format as code properly in my phone. .

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically compile a fragment of code. You could make dynamic variables and then use them.
Check out the related post: [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments).