# Loading the method body from a string?

Tags: c#, reflection, configuration

For *very* special circumstances, I'd like to be able to store C# code in a configuration entry and fill in an empty function with this code at runtime. For example, let's say on initial run I start out with a method such as this:

```
bool Evaluate(int number)
{
   return false;
}
```

I have a configuration entry that looks like this:

```
<add key="EvaluateCode" value="if (number > 5) { return true; } else { return false; }"/>
```

After loading the *EvaluateCode* configuration entry I'd like to replace the function body of *Evaluate* so that it looks like this:

```
bool Evaluate(int number)
{
   if (number > 5) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

After this 'replacement' is made, the *Evaluate* function should behave as the code dictates, just as it would as if the code had not been loaded dynamically.

How could I acheive this in C#?

**Bonus:** What would be the risks of implementing such a feature? How can I mitigate those risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounded like fun.. so I decided to try it.

No need to upvote.. just popping this here so I can reference it in future :)

Given the below class:

```
class DynamicMethodTest {
    private MethodInfo _methodToCall;
    private object _obj;

    public void PerformInjection(string newBody) {
        using (var codeProvider =
       new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider()) {
            var res = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
                new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters() {
                    GenerateInMemory = true
                },
                "public class StubClass { public bool Evaluate(int number) { " + newBody + " }}"
            );

            var type = res.CompiledAssembly.GetType("StubClass");

            _obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            _methodToCall = _obj.GetType().GetMethod("Evaluate");
        }
    }

    public bool Evaluate(int number) {
        if (_methodToCall != null)
            return (bool)_methodToCall.Invoke(_obj, new object[] { number });

        return false;
    }
}
```

We can do this:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dynamicTest = new DynamicMethodTest();

        Console.WriteLine(dynamicTest.Evaluate(15)); // False

        dynamicTest.PerformInjection("if (number > 5) { return true; } else { return false; }");

        Console.WriteLine(dynamicTest.Evaluate(15)); // True

        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

This results in:

```
False
True
```

As output. Basically, before the "Injection" (its not really injection.. its more of a fascade) the method returns false. After "Injection" it returns true (as expected).

Comment: Simon. This is exactly what I was looking for! It's a direct answer to my question that has helped me immensely in what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you are asking for the ability to compile c# code at run time, which is possible, and is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

Comment: I'm amazed I didn't come across this earlier. Thank you for pointing me to it.