# handling name space changes during deserialization of JSON String

Tags: c#, json, redis, json.net, deserialization

I have 2 applications that are communicate amongst each other with the help of a redis Server, In my first application i am able to serialize and de serialize and object of the following type

```
   {
 "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],   [OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService]], mscorlib",
 "71": {
"$type": "OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService",
"SiteID": 2,
"ResourceID": 71,
"ProcessOrder": "001000380873",
"CurrentStatus": 0,
"CycleTime": 55,
"DeviceList": [
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.StackLight, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 71,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.7",
    "ComPort": "COM14"
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.LED, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 71,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.3",
    "ComPort": "COM10",
    "IsMessageDelivered": false,
    "RetryCount": 3,
    "IsRetryRequired": true,
    "_messageHeader": ":*HF601011471",
    "_messageText": "DISPOMELT 5245 BULK - 0020 -投矿物油，树脂，液体树脂和橡胶",
    "_delayedMessageText": "",
    "_counter": 0
  }
],
"UpdateDate": 20150120,
"UpdateTime": 231506,
"CurrentDate": 20150124,
"CurrentTime": 151513,
"CurrentMessage": "DISPOMELT 5245 BULK - 0020 -投矿物油，树脂，液体树脂和橡胶"
  },
  "72": {
"$type": "OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService",
"SiteID": 2,
"ResourceID": 72,
"ProcessOrder": "001000380874",
"CurrentStatus": 0,
"CycleTime": 60,
"DeviceList": [
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.LED, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 72,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.98",
    "ComPort": "COM100",
    "IsMessageDelivered": false,
    "RetryCount": 3,
    "IsRetryRequired": true,
    "_messageHeader": ":*HF601011471",
    "_messageText": "DISPOMELT 5245 BULK - 0050 -熔树脂",
    "_delayedMessageText": "",
    "_counter": 0
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.LED, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 72,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.4",
    "ComPort": "COM11",
    "IsMessageDelivered": false,
    "RetryCount": 3,
    "IsRetryRequired": true,
    "_messageHeader": ":*HF601011471",
    "_messageText": "DISPOMELT 5245 BULK - 0050 -熔树脂",
    "_delayedMessageText": "",
    "_counter": 0
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.StackLight, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 72,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.8",
    "ComPort": "COM15"
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.StackLight, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 72,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.97",
    "ComPort": "COM101"
  }
],
"UpdateDate": 20150120,
"UpdateTime": 231534,
"CurrentDate": 20150124,
"CurrentTime": 151513,
"CurrentMessage": "DISPOMELT 5245 BULK - 0050 -熔树脂"
  },
  "73": {
"$type": "OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService",
"SiteID": 2,
"ResourceID": 73,
"ProcessOrder": "001000375454",
"CurrentStatus": 0,
"CycleTime": 60,
"DeviceList": [
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.LED, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 73,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.5",
    "ComPort": "COM12",
    "IsMessageDelivered": false,
    "RetryCount": 3,
    "IsRetryRequired": true,
    "_messageHeader": ":*HF601011471",
    "_messageText": "XHC 9228 BULK - 0050 -熔树脂",
    "_delayedMessageText": "",
    "_counter": 0
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.StackLight, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 73,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.9",
    "ComPort": "COM16"
  }
],
"UpdateDate": 20150120,
"UpdateTime": 223043,
"CurrentDate": 20150124,
"CurrentTime": 151513,
"CurrentMessage": "XHC 9228 BULK - 0050 -熔树脂"
  },
  "74": {
"$type": "OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService",
"SiteID": 2,
"ResourceID": 74,
"ProcessOrder": "001000375455",
"CurrentStatus": 0,
"CycleTime": 40,
"DeviceList": [
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.LED, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 74,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.2",
    "ComPort": "COM9",
    "IsMessageDelivered": false,
    "RetryCount": 3,
    "IsRetryRequired": true,
    "_messageHeader": ":*HF601011471",
    "_messageText": "XHC 9228 BULK - 0040 -投树脂和剩料:",
    "_delayedMessageText": "",
    "_counter": 0
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.StackLight, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 74,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.1",
    "ComPort": "COM5"
  }
],
"UpdateDate": 20150120,
"UpdateTime": 224143,
"CurrentDate": 20150124,
"CurrentTime": 151513,
"CurrentMessage": "XHC 9228 BULK - 0040 -投树脂和剩料:"
  },
  "75": {
"$type": "OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService",
"SiteID": 2,
"ResourceID": 75,
"ProcessOrder": "001000375456",
"CurrentStatus": 0,
"CycleTime": 50,
"DeviceList": [
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.StackLight, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 75,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.10",
    "ComPort": "COM17"
  },
  {
    "$type": "OPCMessagingService.LED, OPCMessagingService",
    "ResourceId": 75,
    "DeviceIp": "10.142.117.6",
    "ComPort": "COM13",
    "IsMessageDelivered": false,
    "RetryCount": 3,
    "IsRetryRequired": true,
    "_messageHeader": ":*HF601011471",
    "_messageText": "XHC 9228 BULK - 0020 -投矿物油和橡胶、抗氧剂,升温",
    "_delayedMessageText": "",
    "_counter": 0
  }
],
"UpdateDate": 20150120,
"UpdateTime": 225331,
"CurrentDate": 20150124,
"CurrentTime": 151513,
"CurrentMessage": "XHC 9228 BULK - 0020 -投矿物油和橡胶、抗氧剂,升温"
 }
 }
```

I able serialize this and de serialize this in one application but when i try to de serialize this in another application which obviously has a different name space. and i get an exception

Error resolving type specified in JSON 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[OPCMessagingService.Resource, OPCMessagingService]], mscorlib'. Path '$type', line 1, position 138.

I have tried to do the following while de serializing the Json String in another application and it does not work what else can i do to de serialize this object

```
 public static T GetRedisKeyValue<T>(string key)
    {
        if (key.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            GetSentinelMaster();
            using (ConnectionMultiplexer redisClient = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(GetRedisConfiguraion()))
            {
                IDatabase redisDB = redisClient.GetDatabase(); // Getting database connection
                string temp = redisDB.StringGet(key);
                Type type = typeof(T);
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(temp);
                jsonObject["$type"] = type.FullName + ", " + type.Assembly.FullName;
               // JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(temp);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(temp, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full });
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

What else can i do to achieve this.?

Comment: The object type that i am serializing and de serializing is of type Dictionary<int,Resource> Resource has a list of devices and each device which is a base type and each device can be of either LED or StackLight

Comment: Why are you serializing the entire namespace?

Comment: How do i avoid that i am serializing like the following way.
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new JsonSerializerSettings {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects })`
Is there a better way of doing it..?

Comment: Don't serialize the type at all, let JSON.NET figure out what to use on the other side.

Comment: I dont want to do that because i am dealing with a polymorphic list within the object when i dont put the class information it is not able to de serialize  my base class object, it is only de serializing the parent class and not the derived class

Answer (score 4):

The format of the `"$type"` is officially hardcoded to include the CLR namespace of the sending system.  See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130410184516/https://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22429) for confirmation.  So, you can either:

1. Rename your CLR namespaces to match those of the sending system, or
2. Subclass the [`DefaultSerializationBinder`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultSerializationBinder.htm) and use it to rename the CLR namespace names during deserialization by setting it in the [`JsonSerializerSettings.Binder`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Binder.htm).

The following is a first cut at doing this:

```
public class NamespaceMappingSerializationBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder
{
    public string FromNamespace { get; set; }

    public string ToNamespace { get; set; }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        string fixedTypeName;
        if (FromNamespace != null && ToNamespace != null)
        {
            fixedTypeName = typeName.Replace(FromNamespace, ToNamespace);
        }
        else
        {
            fixedTypeName = typeName;
        }
        var type = base.BindToType(assemblyName, fixedTypeName);
        return type;
    }
}
```

Then, when you deserialize your JSON, set the `Binder` in the `JsonSerializerSettings` like so:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, Binder = new NamespaceMappingSerializationBinder { FromNamespace = "From Namespace", ToNamespace = "Your Namespace" } };
```

The type name parsing in the above is extremely crude.  I found a much smarter parser here: [How to parse C# generic type names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532691/how-to-parse-c-sharp-generic-type-names).  You might also need to extend the custom `Binder` to have a dictionary of mappings.

Similarly, if you need to remap the namespace names on serialization, and are working in .Net 4.0 or above, you can override [`BindToName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.bindtoname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I was able to solve the problem.. I have created a new class library for the classes whose data needs to be serialized and added this as a reference to both my applications, In this way i am dealing with the same .NET type in both my applications and it works like a charm.