# Why doesn't Assembly.GetType() work for generic type instances?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a generic class in a separate assembly:

```
class MyGenericClass<T> { }
```

In another assembly, I try to do this:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\path-to\MyClassLibrary.dll");  
var t1 = assembly.GetType("MyClassLibrary.MyGenericClass`1");
var t2 = assembly.GetType("MyClassLibrary.MyGenericClass`1[System.String]");
```

Now, the first call to `GetType` will return a generic type, but the second will return null.

I tested doing the same with the `List<>` type:

```
var assembly2 = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll");
var t3 = assembly2.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");
```

Now, this time it works. The type of `List<String>` is returned. Which leaves me utterly confused.

Why will `GetType()` not get my type when called with a type parameter `[System.String]`, when it is able to get the `List` type when called with the same type parameter?

And is there any other way to get hold of my type? I know I can parse the typename, to extract the parts `MyClassLibrary.MyGenericClass'1` and `[System.String]`, and then instantiate the generic type based on these types, but I would probably mess something up along the way, so I was looking for a simpler, solid, built-in way to get this type object.

Comment: Use `Type.IsGenericType` and `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` to turn "MyGenericClass\`1[System.String]" into "MyGenericClass\`1", `Type.GetGenericArguments()` to get the "System.String" bit, and use `Type.MakeGenericType()` to turn an open generic `MyGenericClass<T>` into a `MyGenericClass<string>`.

Comment: But I don't have the "MyGenericClass`1[System.String" type, all I have is that text string. I need to go from the string to the type.

Comment: How did you end up with that string? That might be the first thing to address. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532691/how-to-parse-c-sharp-generic-type-names

Comment: -grave-1 means that type has 1 generic type. You can check your string for -grave-1 .P.S I Couldnt escape the grave character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string should include the fully qualified named of the type in the other assembly:

```
var t2 = assembly.GetType("MyClassLibrary.MyGenericClass`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]");
```

You might want to consider implementing a custom method that gives you the type:

```
static Type GetType(Assembly assembly, string typeName)
{
    Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
    if (type == null)
    {
        int index = typeName.IndexOf("`1");
        if (index != -1)
        {
            index += 2;
            ReadOnlySpan<char> span = typeName.AsSpan();
            type = Type.GetType(span.Slice(0, index).ToString());
            return type.MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(span.Slice(index + 1, span.Length - index - 2).ToString()));
        }
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: That double bracket syntax got me tripping. Thanks a bunch!