# Best way to run a string as c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let's say I have:

```
@{
var str= "DateTime.Now";
}
```

I want to process this string as a c# code

```
@Html.Raw(App.ProcessAsCode(str));
```

The output should be the current date time.

Comment: Why would you need anything like this?

Comment: "Best" would likely be to "don't do that" - this is asking how to "`eval`". Basically, unless you *need* to accept arbitrary code as text (which is potentially dangerous and generally only useful for things like online "fiddles"), *don't*. So .. what's the *real* problem being solved? xD

Comment: `run a string as c# code` Do you mean what the compiler does ? You **shouldn't** do something like this and I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: @Selman22 Arbitrary code *can* be run, given the appropriate environment and context. Consider how a tool like LINQPad, or the Immediate Window in the debugger.

Comment: @user2864740 ofcourse it is possible if you think like that,what I mean by you can't is it's highly unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Selman22: You're confusing the words "can't" and "probably shouldn't".

Comment: @David okey, I change it,do you happy now :)

Comment: Often when I use a CMS text editor to write html, I think of writing simple code like #DateTime.Now# in the html editor and the page will process it as c# code NOT html. This is just a question that keep coming into my mind sometimes.

Comment: @Ibn-e-Adam If you are using this for a CMS based in .NET I would recommend looking into the .Liquid engine. See: https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/

Comment: @drew_w thank you for your answer. I will have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Final Edit:**

Based on further information - if the goal here is to simply have a formatting engine there are lots of options out there. One such option is based around the .liquid syntax from shopify ([see here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics)). You can find a .NET port of this on gitHub here: https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/. The main purpose of this is to turn something like:

```
 <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
```

Into something like:

```
 <h2>Beef Jerky</h2>
```

I would strongly recommend reading more about the liquid engine and syntax and I believe this will lead you in the right direction. Best of luck!

---

**Initial Answer**

This is definitely possible - although as others have said you will want to be careful in what you do. Using C# the key to compiling and running code generically is the "CSharpCodeProvider" class. Here is a brief example of how that looks:

```
        string[] references = { "System.dll" };
        CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, formattedCode);
```

In this example, "formattedCode" is a string with the C# code. Any references must be manually added. For the full example see this stack question ([How to get a Type from a C# type name string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526024/how-to-get-a-type-from-a-c-sharp-type-name-string/20527253#20527253)).

**NOTE** -- If all you are looking to do here is a format string or something simple like that you might have the user pass in a .NET format string (eg "MM/dd/yyyy"), then use that in a call to the "ToString" method. That would provide the user some configurability, while still making sure your system stays secure. In general running code on a server that hasn't been properly checked/escaped is really dangerous!

*Reference* - For your reference, the [current msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for CSharpCodeProvider also has some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my comment above. Just looking for the fastest way to write html PLUS simple c# snippets in a text editor.

Comment: @Ibn-e-Adam I believe my update (posted to the beginning of the question) is a good place to start. You are basically looking for a templating engine like .liquid. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using a dynamic language such as IronRuby or IronPython.