# Multithreading: prevent Visual Studio from blocking a particular thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, breakpoints

I have a client/server multithreaded application and one thread is used to send a regular `ping` to the server. The problem appears when i want to debug other threads it also blocks my `ping` thread. I already tryed options in Visual Studio `Debug->Windows->Thread` but don't want to use it each time i need to debug a part of my application.

Moreover as I work in a team I can't force my teammates to use this technique. How can I do this without much effort for them (macro, ...)?

Thanks

edit: It's not a duplicate thread! I don't want to use conditional break point every time i need to debug my application! And don't want to complexity the debug procedure for the rest of my team. I searched everywhere and nobody spoke about executing the thread in another `Process`

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the bad grammar i'm french ^^, but no i don't want to set a conditional break point each time i need to debug, same for the rest of my team

Comment: Workaround: assuming *ping* thread is mostly stand-alone thing, convert it to a full child process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, i tryed the @hyde workaround but still have a problem, i can't access the NetworkStream of my main application from my child process but i need it to send some data. This stream is used in one side to send data and on the other to ping the server. Any idea? I will still searching...

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone i finally found an answer to my question!

As @hyde suggested i run my Ping loop in another process, but rather than create another program i dynamically create and execute it from my code

as seen in this topic:
[Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments/826435#826435)

And this more advanced topic:
http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/

But after all i still had a problem... I needed to share my `NetworkStream` between my **Main Application** and his **Child** (needed to send to the same server `Thread`), so i gave to the child the `NetworkStream` by reflection.

Now work correctly, thanks!