# Execute code at runtime with ASP.Net 5

Tags: roslyn, asp.net-core, dynamic-code

I am using Asp.Net 5 CTP6.
I need to execute some c# code at runtime. I know there is some solution and I used some of them but I want to know how can I do this by Roslyn because of platform independency?
By the [old solution that I found](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime) may be exists some problems about multi platform independency. In fact I want to run the web app on windows and Ubuntu.
Thanks

Comment: can you give us a sample of what you want to do please such as the old solution you found

Comment: Consider you have a string of code :

Comment: There is some solutions for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments , http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: Did you read this post https://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/roslyn-compile-c-expressions-without-using-the-scripting-api/ ?

Comment: I read the post. it is not applicable. I need a method for run the plain c# code at run time. I will answer bellow for a better vision:

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how razor does it https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/Compilation/RoslynCompilationService.cs