# Does Visual Studio 2013 provide access to parts of the compiler chain?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, grammar, dsl

I am writing a small DSL.  It consists of a simple Grammar such as this

```
Program =  Commands*
Commands = Keywords '(' STRING ')' ';' 
Keywords = Connect | Disconnect
```

So it matches stuff like

```
Connect("xyz");
```

Are there any built in tools in VS 2013 that will help me NOT have to spin up my own Parser & AST code as well as tools to bind and generate to c#? I am looking at the purest way to do this without loading ANTLR, T4 and all the other 3rd party libs (not yet, this is a prototype). if Visual Studio has something readily available in 2013 without installing Roslyn pre-release, I would appreciate some direction on how to build this micro DSL the fastest and cleanest way.

Comment: Even if you could generate C# code from it "natively" (IL Emit), you would still need to parse your input somehow.

Comment: What, this kind of thing? [How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304655) or [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

Comment: @Mephy Right! I have tried a couple of Parser tools that seem to complicate things because they are not up to date and I found some bugs in the Open source Parser code so I didn't want to spend any more time patching.  I am trying to be resourceful and use whatever VS has to offer.  I guess I am going to just keep the parser that I have. The IL Emit seems it will come in later when a little later on but for now, I might hand map the parse tree to C#. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanCooper Not necessarily what I am looking for but thanks for the good links. The CodeDom seems to be valuable when I tinker with an interpreter soon.