# How to run a string command that is a using decorator pattern

Tags: c#, decorator

I have a piece of code that produces the following output

> new tutor(new lecturer(new coursecoordinator()))

I need a way to allow c# to execute this as a string however after searching I have not been able to find any examples that relate to string such as these. Any ideas as to the best way of approaching this would be appreciated.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/q/826398/3909293

Comment: Or use the Roslyn scripting API. Which might be more fitting if you don't feel like "manually" wrapping it in a class/namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you should be able to do it via the *implicit* operator overload. [Here it is on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)

```
//To use, put in the "tutor" class.
public static implicit operator string(tutor t)
{
    //return the tutor object, in string form.
    //For the example, I just return the .ToString() function found on all objects.
    return t.ToString();
}
```

This will let you seamlessly use the statement "new tutor(new lecturer(new coursecoordinator()))" as a string.
EDIT: I think I misunderstood, perhaps this answer will help a passer-by anyway.