# Roslyn scripting with enforced script interface

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, .net-core, roslyn

I have simple `IScript` interface. And I want enforce that all scripts implement it.

```
public interface IScript<T>
{
    T Execute(object[] args);
}
```

I want to use [Roslyn scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#exprstrong) to achive this. Something like this is possible with [CSScript](http://www.csscript.net/help/script_hosting_guideline_.html) (see **Interface Alignment**).

```
var code = @"
    using System;
    using My.Namespace.With.IScript;                

    public class Script : IScript<string>
    {
        public string Execute()
        {
            return ""Hello from script!"";
        }
    }
";

var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, ScriptOptions.Default);  // + Load all assemblies and references
script.WithInterface(typeof(IScript<string>));                  // I need something like this, to enforce interface
script.Compile();

string result =  script.Execute();                              // and then execute script

Console.WriteLine(result);                                      // print "Hello from script!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type safety is a static thing enforced a compile time (of your application). Creating and running a CSharpScript is done at runtime. So you cannot enforce type safety at runtime.

Maybe CSharpScript is not the right way to go. By using this SO answer, 
[You can compile a piece of C# code into memory and generate assembly bytes with Roslyn.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29417053/880990)

You would then change the line

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

to

```
IScript<string> obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IScript<string>;
if (obj != null) {
    obj.Execute(args);
}
```