# How can I compile a code written in runtime inside the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose I have a talking robot in my game. In the MonoBehavior class, he has the method `public void Talk(string s)`.

Inside my game, I want to have a text field where the user could write the body of a C# function, like that:

> public string MakePhraseFromWords(string[] words){

```
      //user can write code here
      string s = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
          s += words[i];
          if(i < words.Length - 1) s += " ";
      }
      return s;
```

> }

Given the user write this code, I would like to return `s` to the MonoBehaviour class method `Talk` so the robot could say the phrase `s`.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is SUCH a bad idea.   What if the user enters `Process.Start("rmdir /s /q C:\Windows");`?

Comment: I would check for a runtime compiler in the asset store. The most popular one I think is [roslyn](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/roslyn-c-runtime-compiler-142753) but I did not try it

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I was just doing that and found exactly this asset. My question remains the same, but I'll be taking a look at this asset in the meanwhile.

Comment: You can do this without additional packages. [Dynamic C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

Comment: I would rather use some kind of block system with predefined code blocks your User can chose from .. this way you don't have to worry about them doing bad stuff ;)