# Dynamically create a dll file from a string or cs file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, .net-5

The task is that the contents of the dll file becomes known only during the execution of the main program, in which I get the necessary data and form a line or cs file.  Then I need to create a dll from the code I wrote in the line (let's say it's correct and compiles without errors).  Then I will dynamically connect this dll to the main program and use the function from there.

The main problem is in the dynamic creation of the dll file, I did not find a working option.  I am working in WPF .NET 5.0, I tried CodeDOM but there was an error "not supported on this version" so I will be very grateful for any information on how to do it!

Comment: You can use [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/net-core-cross-platform-code-generation-with-roslyn-and-net-core#executing-code-the-emit-apis).

Comment: See [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments),