# Converting last index string to Index object in C#

Tags: c#, .net

We may access the last index of a list/array by the following:

```
var l = new List<string> {"1", "2a", "3cd"};
Console.WriteLine(l[^1]);
```

output: `"3cd"`

May I know if it is possible to cast the string `^1` to index object:
(second line is not working)

```
var s = "^1"
var index = (Index) s;
Console.WriteLine(l[index]);
```

To get the output: `"3cd"`

Comment: you can simply use _Linq_  using `Last()` [Last](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Yea, I know that but I am trying to access the `^1` from a json file and would like to parse it, so it is not what I am looking for

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes

Comment: @lrh09 then write a custom serializer which will read the value of properties with the attribute as an object,

With the information you've provided it's unclear why you would want this.

Comment: You can't. You'd have to provide your own logic to parse the `string`, specifically checking whether it starts with `'^'`.

Comment: You could compile the string in the runtime, however, don't! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To instantiate an [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-index-ctor(system-int32-system-boolean)) for one from the end, do this.

```
var index = new Index(1, true);
```

or

```
var index = Index.FromEnd(1);
```

---

```
var s = "^1"
```

just makes a string that uses the `'^'` char, that can be used in code, to indicate an Index from end.

There is no conversion, explicit or implicit between `string` and [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index?view=net-7.0).

---

If, for some reason you wanted to read a `Index` struct from JSON, you could store both,

```
 int value
```

and the optional

```
 bool fromEnd = false
```

and use those to instantiate a new instance. This would be simpler than writing a parser for strings that contain index expressions.