# Possible to generate code from a text source

Tags: c#

i dont know if it exist or if it exist how its called. Can you generate code/ run code from text?

Let me explain clearly
Ex:

```
string myFunction = "Console.WriteLine("Hello world");";

public static RunMyFunction()
{
    myFunction;
}
```

I know these lines of codes are actually wrong but its just to give an example.

Thank you

Well I searched google but i dont event know how it is named. I really come to you guys as final step.

Comment: search for CodeDOM or T4, which are tools to create source-code at runtime.

Comment: @CSharpMan There are two different problem: are you want to only execute this code, or you want do something else with code?

Comment: As indicated by @MakepeaceGreatAgain, CodeDOm is the solution. refer to Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments :https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+compilation+of+code+C%23&client=firefox-b-d&ei=v1gtZKwc86qR1Q-72K_oCQ&ved=0ahUKEwjs96H7zpL-AhVzVaQEHTvsC50Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=dynamic+compilation+of+code+C%23&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyCAghEBYQHhAdOgoIABBHENYEELADSgQIQRgAUMYGWPUQYLcVaAFwAXgAgAFyiAHGAZIBAzEuMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Comment: As indicated by @MakePeaceGreatAgain, CodeDOM is the solution, see  `Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Comment: @RezaNoei no i made an app with dynamically created panels that let the user build a request but it cannot actually work as some part of code are text.

Comment: ok a big thank you to all to pointed me in the right direction i will look into it!!! Appreciate

Comment: Taking c# code as text from the user and executing it is rarely a good idea. It is a security nightmare, regular users will have no idea what to do, and programmers will be irritated by the poor development environment. I would suggest either creating a plugin system, or take a much more limited type of input, like regex, or a mathematical expression.

Comment: @JonasH : Security issues are not a problem, when you provide to the user a desktop software where user may write some code for its own purpose (assuming that he can also create other programs on its computer).