# Code Generator to generate a static class holding constants of sub-classes names on-the-fly when a new sub-class is added to a .net project

Tags: c#, prism, code-generation

I am developing a Revit addin utilizing the Prism library as my MVVM/IOC framework.
The addin relies heavily on Prism's DialogService to display various dialogs for several tools.

**I want to avoid hard-coding dialog names** whenever using the `IDialogService.ShowDialog(dialogName, dialogParams, callBackAction)` function.
So I am thinking of introducing a **static class** in the abstraction layer that holds the names of all the dialogs defined in the UI layer assembly.

**Instead of maintaining this class manually**, is there a way to equip my solution with a **code generator** that will update this class whenever I:

- Add a new dialog sub-class to the UI project? **Or**
- Register a new dialog with the `IContainerRegistry.RegisterDialog<DlgUserControlType, DlgViewModelType>()` ?

I'm not sure if this is a naive approach, so please feel free to point out any "smell" in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You can use the .NET `Reflection` library to determine all your add-in's class names. If the new dialog sub-class follows a suitable naming convention, you can easily use Reflection to extract the `dialogName`, `dialogParams`, and `callBackAction` information required from the class name and its other attributes.

Comment: As far as I know, Reflection happens after you compile. What I'm looking for is code generation in design time (for example when a new file is added to the source-code).
Just like the code generated for you in the background when you add a new Win-Form for example.

Comment: You can mix compilation and reflection at will. Both can happen in real-time, and you can pass information back an forth between the two processes, cf. [dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments).